# How to stack 2 raw videos (yuv) horizontally using ffplay & lavfi?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I know how to stack 2 videos horizontally when they are in a container format using the following ffplay command:

ffplay -f lavfi “movie=movie1.mov[v0];movie=movie2.mov[v1];[v0][v1]hstack"

If my videos, however, are in yuv format where can I specify the pix_fmt & video_size flags?

Comment: An inefficient "solution" is to re-mux rawvideo: `ffmpeg -framerate 24 -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1280x720 -i input.yuv -c copy output.mkv`

Comment: Yes, presently I am doing this containerization offline and using ffplay on them. Would be nice if all this could be done on the fly.

Comment: Not implemented - the movie src filters don't read input format args.